# Make website point to a host but a singular app on website point to a different host

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting, nameservers

I'm currently maintaining the website Intellaren.com which uses Arvixe hosting service. However, I would like to run a war file on this website at intellaren.com/intellibe.

The war file is hosted on intellibe.heroku.com but whenever I link my website to it - I get the error: Unable to resolve the server's DNS address.

I think I might have to change some nameservers but for the life of me, can't find a specific solution that works.  Any help is appreciated.